# Keep rows which have datas for all days in a date range grouped by ID

Tags: r

I have daily datas and I bind them into a single dataframe :

```
datas <- data.frame(id1 = c("x", "y", "x", "y", "z", "x", "z"), 
                    id2 = c("x2", "y2", "x2", "y2", "z2", "x2", "z2"), 
                    code = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2"),
                    var = runif(7),
                    date = do.call(c, mapply(rep, seq(Sys.Date() - 2, Sys.Date(), by = 1), c(2, 3, 2))))

id1 id2 code        var       date
1   x  x2    1 0.56751754 2015-07-01
2   y  y2    2 0.04970992 2015-07-01
3   x  x2    1 0.56162037 2015-07-02
4   y  y2    2 0.96617891 2015-07-02
5   z  z2    2 0.50994534 2015-07-02
6   x  x2    1 0.70093692 2015-07-03
7   z  z2    2 0.02034940 2015-07-03
```

I would like to group by id1, id2 and if there is data for each day in an exact date range, keep the rows.

```
# Output expected with this date range :

dateStart <- Sys.Date() - 2
dateEnd <- Sys.Date()
dateSeq <- seq(dateStart, dateEnd, by = 1)

"2015-07-01" - "2015-07-03"
id1 id2 code        var       date
1   x  x2    1 0.56751754 2015-07-01
3   x  x2    1 0.56162037 2015-07-02
6   x  x2    1 0.70093692 2015-07-03

# Output expected with this date range :

dateStart <- Sys.Date() - 1
dateEnd <- Sys.Date()
dateSeq <- seq(dateStart, dateEnd, by = 1)

"2015-07-02" - "2015-07-03"
3   x  x2    1 0.56162037 2015-07-02
5   z  z2    2 0.50994534 2015-07-02
6   x  x2    1 0.70093692 2015-07-03
7   z  z2    2 0.02034940 2015-07-03
```

Also do you think this is a great format, or do you think I should store my data differently?

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt at a solution, (though I think there might be a more elegant way).

The gist of the solution is to use a full join and only keep the record if it is "complete", i.e. it has to join the `dateSeq` completely, nothing more, nothing less.

**1**

Create a `data.frame` with an indicator and the date range:

```
dateSeq <- data.frame(date=seq(dateStart, dateEnd, by = 1), ind=1)
```

**2**

Using `dplyr`, We can then use `group_by` to firstly group the data by `id1`, `id2`, then we can use the `do` function to apply the `full_join` and `filter` to check for complete records, by checking if the columns `id1`, `id2`, and the indicator variable created in **1** `ind`, all have no `NA`'s:

```
datas %>% 
  group_by(id1, id2) %>%
  do(filter(full_join(dateSeq, .), 
            all(!is.na(ind)) && all(!is.na(id1)) && all(!is.na(id2))))
```

---

So then using this code with the code you have above, we have:

```
library(dplyr)
dateStart <- Sys.Date() - 2
dateEnd <- Sys.Date()
dateSeq <- seq(dateStart, dateEnd, by = 1)
dateSeq <- data.frame(date=seq(dateStart, dateEnd, by = 1), ind=1)

datas %>% 
  group_by(id1, id2) %>%
  do(filter(full_join(dateSeq, .), 
            all(!is.na(ind)) && all(!is.na(id1)) && all(!is.na(id2)))) 

dateStart <- Sys.Date() - 1
dateEnd <- Sys.Date()
dateSeq <- seq(dateStart, dateEnd, by = 1)
dateSeq <- data.frame(date=seq(dateStart, dateEnd, by = 1), ind=1)

datas %>% 
  group_by(id1, id2) %>%
  do(filter(full_join(dateSeq, .), 
            all(!is.na(ind)) && all(!is.na(id1)) && all(!is.na(id2))))
```

Which has the output:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
Groups: id1, id2

        date ind id1 id2 code       var
1 2015-07-01   1   x  x2    1 0.7919067
2 2015-07-02   1   x  x2    1 0.1038065
3 2015-07-03   1   x  x2    1 0.5850392
```

and

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 6]
Groups: id1, id2

        date ind id1 id2 code       var
1 2015-07-02   1   z  z2    2 0.7614406
2 2015-07-03   1   z  z2    2 0.5015336
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser ! Though I tested it on my datas (11M rows) and the progress bar started with `Joining by: "date"|                                                       |  0% ~53 h remaining`. Wow 53h for real ?!

Comment: I suspect because its doing a full join. There are probably quicker ways of doing it, but it will depend on how many date ranges, and how many times you're doing it like this.

Comment: I have 749,357 grousp (id1, id2) and 46 dates. I read somewhere that dplyr is slow when there is a lot of groups